# Creating a separate object for each row of results-set in MyBatis

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis, ibatis

I am using MyBatis to query DB. I am trying to separate out the results into different objects, but MyBatis is combining the results. I mean, when I try to map the results as explained below, I get a list of 2 `Make` objects with Toyota having 3 `Model` objects in the `models` List and Honda having 2 `Model` objects in the `models` list.

Instead I want to get a list of 5 objects and each of them having 1 `Model` object in the `models` List.

Could anyone help me out here?

I have 2 POJOs as below

```
class Make {
    long makeId;
    String makeName;
    List<Model> models;

    // Getter and setters
}

class Model {
    long modelId;
    String modelName;
}
```

I have a query that extracts the results in the below format.

[image]

My Resultset looks like

```
<resultMap type='Make' id='resultMap'>
    <id property='makeId' column='make_id' />
    <result property='makeName' column='make_name' />
    <collection property="models" ofType="Model" javaType="list">
        <id property='modelId' column='model_id' />
        <result property='modelName' column='model_name' />
    </collection>
</resultMap>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you basically want to identify the parent object `Make` by the composite key of `make_id` and `model_id`.

The following result map may return the result you expect.

```xml
<resultMap type='Make' id='resultMap'>
  <id property='makeId' column='make_id' />
  <id column="model_id" /><!-- added -->
  <result property='makeName' column='make_name' />
  <collection property="models" ofType="Model" javaType="list">
    <id property='modelId' column='model_id' />
    <result property='modelName' column='model_name' />
  </collection>
</resultMap>
```

By omitting `property` attribute from the `<id />`, the column `model_id` is not mapped to `Make`, but is used to identify it.